# register 4 arguments on django admin - TypeError: register() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)

Tags: python, django

here is my code.. and I know that I am not alowed to give 4 arguments to register() in django admin.py, but I want to use ProductAdmin and ProductExportImportAdmin together for Product model.. is there possible I am doing that? Is there a way?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Supplier, Customer, Product, PoOrder
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
from import_export import resources


class ProductResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        exclude = ('id', 'created_at', 'edited_at',)


class ProductExportImportAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = ProductResource


class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['code','name']


admin.site.register(Supplier)
admin.site.register(Customer)
admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin, ProductExportImportAdmin)
admin.site.register(PoOrder)
```

Comment: Perhaps you want inlines? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects

Comment: I tried this before.. it won't allowed me.. and here is the error: ERRORS:
<class 'masterdata.admin.ProductAdmin'>: (admin.E104) 'masterdata.admin.ProductExportImportAdmin' must inherit from 'InlineModelAdmin'.

Answer (score 0):

GOT IT!!!

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Supplier, Customer, Product, PoOrder
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
from import_export import resources


class ProductResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        exclude = ('id', 'created_at', 'edited_at',)


class ProductAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    resource_class = ProductResource

    search_fields = ['code','name']


admin.site.register(Supplier)
admin.site.register(Customer)
admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
admin.site.register(PoOrder)
```